# How to restart service file without passowrd?

Tags: ubuntu, service, sudo

my service file is inside bin/systemd/system my_service.service, I want to restart it using (in c++). I am using ubuntu 20.04

```
system("sudo systemctl restart my_service.service");
```

but it's not working as It requires the password of the user, I do not want to write the password in the code.

I already tried doing

```
sudo visudo
```

and editing it like

```
orangepi ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/systemd/system restart my_service.service
```

but it is not working